# SKVideoNode invisible in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, ios9, xcode7

I have an SKScene which is essentially a wall of tiles, each of which is either an image ([SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image_name"]) or a video ([SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:avPlayer])

This code works fine when building with Xcode 6.4 for iOS 8 or 9, and fine when building with Xcode 7.2 for iOS 8 BUT when I build with Xcode 7.2 for iOS 9 the videos are invisible.
I can see they are playing as I have a notification which fires when the videos end (in order to loop them) and it is firing as expected.

I have tried experimenting with the zPosition of the nodes as I have seen other people suggesting it, but have had no success with this.

Any ideas?